# Unknown insect in southern Kansas

Tags: species-identification, wasps

My wife and I just moved to Southern Kansas and are still learning the local fauna could anyone please tell us what type of insect this is.[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a male Metric Paper Wasp (Polistes metricus).

Bugguide is an an authoritative source for arthropods in North America and describes these as:

> Very dark--abdomen is black... thorax dark reddish-brown with black
> lines. Tibiae and tarsi are yellow (1). Males, like those of most
> Polistes species (exception being P. annularis), have a yellow face,
> while females have a reddish-brown face.

https://bugguide.net/node/view/60264

We see here that the abdomen, thorax and leg segment colours all match-up. The yellow seen at the top of the face is enough to separate it as a male.

Looking at iNaturalist for vespoid wasps in Kansas, we see that the most commonly observed wasp is this species.

[image: Wasps in Kansas sorted by most-observed]

Further, looking at the other species there in Kansas for similarly-coloured wasps, there are a few dark ones with reddish colouring but they would have red or yellow stripes in the abdomen, not all-black as this species has.

https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=25&taxon_id=48740&view=species

Bugguide has an extensive gallery of photos of this species, and I found one other with no wings:

https://bugguide.net/node/view/987823/bgimage

This is the only photo I found in the >1000 photos I browsed in Bugguide and iNaturalist of this species that shows a specimen with no wings. So it is probably not a natural occurrence for these wasps to lose their wings (like from some natural predator or mating or feasting ritual or anything) -  from the crumpled-look of the wings in the photo, my best guess is that these wings have been melted.